# can't get razor runtime compilation to work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to get Razor Runtime compilation to work.  I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, and I've installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation from Nuget, and I have             services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); in the startup file.  I thought that, once I had done that, the Runtime compilation just happened automatically, however, no such luck.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.
Nick

Comment: Did you try to check your code against [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you have enabled the `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`, you should make sure you have saved your edited cshtml razor page and refresh the page, then you will see the page has been updated.